# Continued fraction for $\sqrt 2$

Tags: number-theory, continued-fractions

I discovered this continued fraction for $\sqrt 2$ but could not find any sources in which it appeared. It goes as follows:

\begin{equation}
\sqrt{2} = 1 + \frac{1 + \frac{1 + \frac{1 + \dots}{3 + \dots}}{3 + \frac{1 + \dots}{3 + \dots}}}{3 + \frac{1 + \frac{1 + \dots}{3 + \dots}}{3 + \frac{1 + \dots}{3 + \dots}}}
\end{equation}

I can show that it approaches $\sqrt{2}$ via a computer program, but see no feasible way to prove it.

Comment: If it is meaningful and equal to some $k$ then presumably $k=1+\frac{k}{2+k}$

Comment: First glance tells me that this can be written recursively as $\sqrt{2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$, where $a_0=1$, and $a_n=1+\frac{a_{n-1}}{2+a_{n-1}}$. If you can prove this converges, then just take the limit and you get the limit $a$ by solving $a=1+\frac{a}{2+a}$ and noting that $a>0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your continued fraction is essentially the 'infinite image' of the map $x\mapsto f(x)=1+\dfrac x{2+x}$ (can you see why?) and so any limit $\alpha$ of that map must satisfy $\alpha=1+\dfrac{\alpha}{2+\alpha}$. Multiplying both sides by $2+\alpha$ and simplifying gives the equation $\alpha^2=2$, so $\sqrt{2}$ must be the limit *if it exists*. To show that the limit exists, you want to show that $f(x)$ is what's called a [Contraction Mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_mapping) over a suitable section of the real line — that is to say, that the distance between $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ is always smaller than the distance between $x$ and $y$ within that domain. The Banach fixed-point theorem then guarantees that it has a (unique) fixed point in that region. The easiest way to show that $f()$ is a contraction mapping is to show that the derivative is less than $1$ in the domain in question (it's a little bit tricky to prove that this implies that $f()$ is a contraction mapping, but not too hard, and it should hopefully be intuitively clear). Now, the derivative of $f$ is $f'(x)=\dfrac{2}{(2+x)^2}$, and this is clearly less than $1$ for any $x\geq 0$, so the conditions hold and the limit is well-defined.

As for why showing convergence matters in a problem like this, consider the expression $6-2\times(6-2\times(6-2\times(6-\ldots)))$; applying the same argument shows that the limit $\alpha$ satisfies $\alpha=6-2\alpha$, so $\alpha=2$ if the limit exists. But iterating the map $x\mapsto 6-2x$ blows up to infinity for any starting value of $x$, so the original expression doesn't have any proper meaning (over the real numbers).

Comment: The map $x\mapsto6-2x$ does not "blow up" for the starting value $x=2$

Answer (score 2):

Let $x = \frac {1 + \frac {1 + \cdots}{3+\cdots}}{3 + \frac {1 + \cdots}{3+\cdots}}$

$x = \frac {1+x}{3+x}\\
x^2+ 3x = 1+x\\
x^2 + 2x - 1 = 0\\
x = -1 \pm \sqrt {2}$

We know that $x>0$ so we can discard the negative value.

$1 + x = \sqrt 2$

Comment: This shows the limit if it exists, but doesn't handle the question of convergence.